# Shortcode content does not show in feed discription/excerpt

Tags: shortcode, excerpt, feed, description

I have a shortcode for my content. This shortcode organizes a couple of things in my posts on the frontend.

However, when I look at my feed, the content in the  entirely leaves out any content from my shortcode and only starts after the shortcode content.

When I take the content outside of my shortcode it shows up in the

Why is my shortcode content not showing in the description of the feed? It worked great before I introduced the shortcode!

I have found a similar issue here with no resolution: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/execute-shortcodes-in-feed-content

**Update:**
So I just read that shortcodes are being stripped by wordpress. How can I prevent this behaviour?

I have also tried this without any luck: [the_excerpt and shortcodes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42743/the-excerpt-and-shortcodes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I had to write my own custom excerpt like such:

```
function custom_excerpt($text = '') {
    $raw_excerpt = $text;
    if ( '' == $text ) {
        $text = get_the_content('');
                // $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
        $text = do_shortcode( $text );
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 200);
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }
    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
remove_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt'  );
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt');
```