# Stop strip_shortcodes() stripping content inside shortcodes

Tags: shortcode, excerpt

I have this shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('refer', function($atts, $text)
{
    $defaults = ['link' => '', 'nofollow' => true];
    $atts     = shortcode_atts($defaults, $atts, 'refer' );
    $nofollow = $atts['nofollow'] ? 'rel="nofollow"' : 'external';

    return sprintf('<a href="%s" %s>%s</a>', esc_url($atts['link']), $nofollow, $text);
});
```

with demo post content:

> [refer link="http://www.lipsum.com"]Lorem Ipsum[/refer] is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. [refer link="http://www.lipsum.com"]Lorem Ipsum[/refer] has been the standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing [refer link="http://www.lipsum.com"]Lorem Ipsum[/refer] passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

The loop to echo out the excerpt:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_excerpt();
endwhile;
```

The result:

> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.  has been the standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. […]

Notice that all `Lorem Ipsum` words were stripped from the excerpt.

After looking over [the_excerpt()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/#source-code) and other related functions, I found out the problem was caused by [strip_shortcodes()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/strip_shortcodes/#source-code) inside [wp_trim_excerpt](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_excerpt/) function.

But because of `strip_shortcodes()` has no filters, how can I change its behavior?

Comment: Found: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33133953/1743124 and https://wordpress.org/support/topic/stripping-shortcodes-keeping-the-content#post-2770209. Have a look.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam The second solution works great! Thank you!

Comment: If the plan is to allow the user to selectively add the rel="nofollow" attribute to links, then there might be other [alternatives](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/228553/26350) than shortcodes ;-)

Comment: @birgire I have already added that question and your answer in my favorited list. The shortcode  is for demonstration only :-)

Comment: cool, I look forward to see what possible workarounds you come up with, for the general shortcode case ;-)

Comment: @MayeenulIslam _somebody_ should post that as an answer :)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee done as community wiki. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the filters in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```

Props: @bainternet ([Source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42745/22728))

Or, use your own filter on `get_the_excerpt`. Put this in your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function custom_excerpt($text = '') {
    $raw_excerpt = $text;
    if ( '' == $text ) {
        $text = get_the_content('');
                // $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
        $text = do_shortcode( $text );
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }
    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
remove_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt'  );
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt'  );
```

This will allow shortcodes in `the_excerpt()`.

Props to @keesiemeijer ([source](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/stripping-shortcodes-keeping-the-content#post-2770209))