# Auto-generated excerpt with shortcode and read more button/text link

Tags: filters, shortcode, excerpt, buttons

From this thread: [the_excerpt and shortcodes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42743/the-excerpt-and-shortcodes/203646#203646) I pulled this snippet of code from @Programmer Dan that is working well to include executed shortcodes in autogenerated excerpts

```
    add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt', 10);
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'my_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', 99, 1);
function my_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($text) {
    if(''==$text) {
        $text= preg_replace('/\s/', ' ', wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_content('')));
        $text= explode(' ', $text, 56);
        array_pop($text);
        $text= implode(' ', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

My problem is I can't figure out how to also add either button or text link for read more going back to original article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the source code of [`get_the_excerpt`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/) you see that there actually two arguments passed to the filter: the excerpt text and the post object. Your are only passing the text, while you need the post object to know the permalink.

So you should change these lines:

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'my_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', 99, 1);
function my_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($text) {
```

to:

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'my_custom_wp_trim_excerpt', 99, 2);
function my_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($text,$post) {
```

Now you have the post object available in your filter function and you can use [`get_permalink($post)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) to retrieve the link to the post and do whatever you like with it. For instance like this:

```
function my_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($text) {
    if(''==$text) {
        $text= preg_replace('/\s/', ' ', wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_content('')));
        $text= explode(' ', $text, 56);
        array_pop($text);
        $text= implode(' ', $text);
    }
    $text = $text . '<a href="' . get_permalink($post) . '">Link to post</a>';
    return $text; }
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very informative and helpful, but I'm still not clear on just how to use 'get_permalink($post)' in this scenario -- together with the text output how would I add that to the string that gets returned to add some html ... something along the lines of '  $something = $something . `<a href="' . get_permalink($post). '"><button class="read-more-btn" type="button" value="read_more">Read More</button></a>';`

Comment: Yes. `get_permalink` returns a string and you can concatenate that to your excerpt including any html you like before returning the completed string.

Comment: Hi - I just don't know how to add that to the above code...

Comment: I have updated the answer with some basic php.